How could an anonymous user attempt PutBucketAcl on a private bucket?
I have private buckets on AWS S3. I have AWS Config to ensure they are private and I believe the AWS policy settings are all set so that no-one can have access.
I have CloudWatch alarms for anyone trying to get access (Get/Set Bucket Acls etc) and those have been triggered in the last four weeks.
The origin is 'anonymous' AWS user coming through the API.
However, I don't understand how they could know the bucket name such that they can even try to put Acl in the first place?
Have they got a list of our buckets or is there a numerical enumeration they can use?
Is there anything I can do to stop them even getting this far?
